# How do I test django with gitlab ci

Tags: django, gitlab, django-unittest, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci server that works fine and can connect with my gitlab server,Please can any one point me in the right directing on how to run my django unittest/builds using gitlab-ci runner thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry if answering a bit of an old question, but it seems that the general way to run a build is using a [gitlab-ci runner](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/#gitlab-runner); which seems to be an application which interacts with [gitlab-ci API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/README.html).

The way some people are running runners is with docker images (to "freeze" the build/test environment). See these links for basic information on how this works:

- https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-runner
- https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-runner-gitlab
- https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci

Finally see this [python runner image](https://github.com/cardoe/docker-gitlab-ci-runner-python) for running builds on your python projects.